# Repeat request multiple times with different params using RxJava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I need to load some data from server page by page until all the data is loaded. The data is considered to be fully loaded if at some point I received fewer items than I've requested. This is the working solution that I have right now:

```
return Observable.fromCallable { 0 }
        .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .repeat()
        .scan { previousPage, _ -> previousPage + 1}
        .concatMap { doLongFetch(it) }
        .takeUntil { it.size < 100 }

fun doLongFetch(page: Int): Observable<List<ListItem>>() {
    //Here I do the loading
}
```

However, there's a problem with the source observable. As you can see, it emits new values every 500 milliseconds to provide some input for the scan function. The delay is required since otherwise, it would emit thousands of values in a very short period of time, which is not required at all. Ideally, I want to remove that delay completely and make sure that the source observable emits another value only after the downstream has handled the previous one (meaning that the data has been requested and processed).

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: Create a serialized `PublishSubject` and call `onNext` when you want the next page (remove delay and repeat).

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. Can I assume though that it's not possible to do what I'm trying to do without introducing an additional subject? Having a subject doesn't look as elegant as a simple chain of operators

Comment: You'd have to encompass the whole page processing which would require more operators, conversions and careful repetition design.